# infinite scrolling background horizontally

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, sprite

I have created an infinite scrolling background that scrolls horizontally. when it gets to the top it stops. how do you get it to continue instead of stopping at the top. this is the code.

override func update(currentTime: NSTimeInterval) {

```
    background.position = CGPoint(x: background.position.x , y: background.position.y - 1)
    background2.position = CGPoint(x: background2.position.x , y: background2.position.y - 1)

    if (background.position.y < -background.size.width) {
        background.position = CGPointMake(background2.position.x + background2.size.height, background.position.y)

    }

    if (background2.position.y < -background2.size.width) {
        background2.position = CGPointMake(background.position.x + background.size.height, background2.position.y)
    }
```

Comment: Hello @Seyi Check this article, http://iosdevelopertips.com/user-interface/creating-circular-and-infinite-uiscrollviews.html

Comment: This makes no sense,  why are you comparing y to the width

Comment: In case you are unaware, horizontal is left to right and vertical is top to bottom,  so scrolling horizontally to the top makes no sense.